# How can I use Mockito for unit testing in case with inheritance?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have three classes which I need to test. In fact I need to write some unit tests to cover all functionality of this classes. But the problem is I don't know from what point I need to start. In my case It's really important to use Mockito framework. So I would be appriciated for any help.

Here is my classes

```
public class Girl extends Father {

    protected Girl(Info info) {
        super(info);
    }

    public Boy create(String param) {
        return new Boy(info, param);
    }
}
```

Boy class

```
public class Boy extends Father {
    private final String param;

    public Boy(Info info, String param) {
        super(info);
        this.param = param;
    }

    public void method (){
        new RemoteService().invoke(param);
    }
}
```

Info class (this class I don't need to test)

```
public class Info {
    private Integer accountNumber;

    public Integer getAccountNumber() {
        return accountNumber;
    }

    public void setAccountNumber(Integer accountNumber) {
        this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
    }
}
```

And Father class
    public abstract class Father {

```
    protected final Info info;

    public Father(Info info) {
        this.info = info;
    }
}
```

Comment: ``Girl`` extends ``Father``? I am open minded but I feel like something is wrong here...

Comment: Doesn't seem much to test here.

Comment: Why do you think you need to use Mockito? What do you want to test?

Comment: One of suggestions which I received was to check is `Info` instance actually passed to `Father` with `super(info)` in `Girl` class.

Comment: What do you want to test, and what have you tried so far ?

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis I'm actually want to test constructors invoking and passing the parameters.

Comment: Where does Mockito come into play?

Comment: And I need to test this method `Boy create(String param)`

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis I think Mockito allows to play with inheritance and to check passing params.

Comment: A girl extends a father and creates a boy? Let's hope these are just some abstract names. As to your question: testing inheritance by itself doesn't make sense, it is essentially a language construct. What is it you want to test at the `create` method?

Comment: Yes. That's right. My goal was to write some unit tests for a `Girl` class and method `create` in particular.

Comment: Actually I don't know is it possible to cover this class with unit tests at all.

Comment: Fine, you want to test `create` method and control that the created `Boy` has the correct `Info` when you looks at it as a `Father`. But why do you want to use Mockito for that ? Do you want to mock `Info` ?

Comment: In fact I can check is `Parant` class got the `info`. But how can I do that with mockito?

Comment: @Serge Ballesta Maybe because Mockito has a proper functionality for this case?

Comment: I can imagine testing that with Junit, but IMHO Mockito is useless here.

Comment: So It's impossible to make some unit tests for `Girl` and `Boy` classes at all? Actually are they testable?

Comment: All in your classes seems to be easyly testable (still no use for Mockito at first sight), except `Boy.method()` where you create a new object that is immediately destroyed and where Powermock would be useful. Did you confuse in your question Mockito (create mock objects) and Powermock (test constructor or static methods) ?

Comment: Yes I did. I've never heard about Powermock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing for Mockito or PowerMock to do here.  The only condition that you could possibly test would be that `create` in the `Girl` class makes a new `Boy` with the right `info` and `param`.  Assuming that you have the appropriate getter methods, you could do it like this, in the `GirlTest` class.  No mocking is required.

```
@Test
public void createMakesNewBoy() {
    Info testInfo = new Info();
    Girl toTest = new Girl(testInfo);
    Boy created = toTest.create("param");
    assertEquals("param", created.getParam());
    assertSame(testInfo, created.getInfo());
}
```

Other than the `create` method, you don't have any methods that it makes sense to test.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test constructors or static methods, you should look at a tool like [Powermock](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/) which is currently used in complement to Mockito to deal with those use cases that are not easy with Mockito. The referenced page has a lot of documentation and pointer to examples. The most interesting page (as you spoke of Mockito) should be [MockitoUsage](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage)

Comment: I find this answer a bit misleading.  Powermock will help you **stub** or **verify** constructors or static methods; but it won't help with actually **testing** them.  Testing constructors and static methods requires the same techniques as testing any other methods.

Comment: @DavidWallace You are right. If you feel stating that in comments is not enough, feel free to edit my post.